# equality and not equality operators in Python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, equality

Let's say I have these two lists:

```
number_list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
number_list_2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

then let's say that I want to know if the two lists are equal (There are a lot of ways to do this in Python and it's not what I'm looking for, also this is not a good approach in Python to do this)

solution 1:

```
def list_equality_1(l1, l2):

    # Assuming that two array like objects have the same length
    length = len(l1)

    for i in range(length):
        if l1[i] == l2[i]:
            continue
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

solution 2:

```
def list_equality_1(l1, l2):

    # Assuming that two array like objects have the same length
    length = len(l1)

    for i in range(length):
        if l1[i] != l2[i]:
            return False
    return True
```

In both of these solutions, each time we loop, we are evaluating the if statement, for the first one we are evaluating for equality and for the second one we are evaluating for not equality of the elements in the ith place.
My question is which one is better? evaluating for the 'equality' first and use else statement, or evaluating for the 'not equality'? I want to know how the compiler deals with this.

Comment: If you want to know how the compiler deals with each, give each function to `dis`: `from dis import dis; dis(list_equality_1); dis(list_equality_2) `. I don't think there will be any surprises; I would expect the compiled code to look very similar. I think readability is the only concern here. The fact that you need a `continue` in the first way though would make me use the second.

Comment: Well… the first one is needlessly verbose, if you ask me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *My question is which one is better?*

My answer is that the second one is better.

- You waste less lines
- Everybody knows the `continue` is anyway implicit

I always use the second code when I have to, even thought as you said before there are several other ways to compare `list`s in Python, I'm talking of C/C++.

---

```
length = len(l1)

for i in range(length):
    if l1[i] != l2[i]:
        return False
return True
```

This code is uselessy verbose, I would shorten it this way.

```
for first, second in zip(l1, l2):
    if first != second:
        return False
return True
```

It could be useful to you the reading of the documentation about built-in class [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

> By default, `zip()` stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted. It will ignore the remaining items in the longer iterables, cutting off the result to the length of the shortest iterable.

So this alternative method will only work with `len(l1) == len(l2)`, but this is true with your code too.

---

> *As I said before I want to know how the compiler deals with equality (==) and not equality (!=) operators.*

Well, I don't think you ever compile your Python code, that's why you don't have an `.asm`, `.o` or `.exe` file to inspect.

> *I want to know the complexity of these operators.*

They both have temporal complexity of [`O(1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation).

## Disassembly

---

[image: Do you see any difference?]

The two are equivalent, they generate almost the same set of instructions, except for a couple of things after line 100, but it won't affect the performance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not looking for a way to solve this problem. As I said before I want to know how the compiler deals with equality (==) and not equality (!=) operators. and also negating in Python. I want to know the complexity of these operators. and is it more complex for the compiler to solve it with the 'not equality' or not?

Comment: @winter, I edited the answer, but I'm going to disassemble your functions to tell you if there are any differences for real. Any difference won't affect your performance anyway.

Comment: Happy to help @winter, I hope somebody else will upvote this answer because it took me a few time to copy the functions in the repl 

Comment: Maybe I didn't ask my question very well and some people would have misunderstood! 
Thank you for your time and effort! I won't forget this my friend! You've got a big badge in my heart!